MariaDB in Docker - MariaDB Connector/Python was build with MariaDB Connector/C version 3.3.3, but loaded Connector/C library has version 10.3.39
I can't figure out the error in my Docker container.
I am using python:3.9-buster
i am downloading, I think, the correct Connector/C version for MariaDB
RUN wget https://dlm.mariadb.com/2678574/Connectors/c/connector-c-3.3.3/mariadb-connector-c-3.3.3-debian-bullseye-amd64.tar.gz \
    -O mariadb-connector-c.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzf mariadb-connector-c.tar.gz --strip-components=1 -C /usr && \
    rm mariadb-connector-c.tar.gz

But I can't figure out why I'm still getting the error.
The full error line if that helps
/app/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mariadb/connections.py:85: RuntimeWarning: MariaDB Connector/Python was build with MariaDB Connector/C version 3.3.3 but loaded Connector/C library has version 10.3.39

I followed the trace of this post: Mariadb in Docker: MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.2.4, found version 3.1.16 but it did not work

It seems that you didn't install MariaDB Connector/C in the right place, so instead of using the downloaded libmariadb.so from Connector/C 3.3.3, MariaDB Connector/Python tries to load libmariadb.so from an installed  MariaDB 10.3. I would recommend to upgrade (both buster and MariaDB 10.3 reached end of life). MariaDB Connector/Python should build and work also with a recent MariaDB server version.
